# How do I make Firefox's AwesomeBar autocomplete just like Chrome?

Tags: firefox, google-chrome

Chrome almost always autocompletes text entered on Omnibar. I set Firefox's "browser.urlbar.autoFill" to "true" so it autocompletes the text sometimes, but not as often as Chrome's Omnibar.

How do I make it autocomplete just like the way Omnibar does it?

Answer (score 3):

You could try [this](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/8823/) addon.

Answer (score 1):

Try **[Prospector - Speak Words](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/prospector-speak-words/)**.

> This restartless add-on helps you easily get to sites that you
>   frequently visit by typing just a few letters in the location bar and
>   having Firefox fill in the rest of the word as well as selecting the
>   first result. From there, just press [return] to go to that page!

[image]

Comment: Please add some details to this answer.  Link-only answers aren't very useful and are discouraged.

Comment: Finally, something that works for me! Haven't used it long enough, but it does auto-fill the superbar with the rest of the first result

Comment: Except typing goog and enter takes me to maps.google.com on my browser. That, plus a couple of other annoyances, made me uninstall.

Answer (score 1):

A very late reply

[Firefox 12 autocompletes url](http://www.browsomatic.com/2012/01/firefox-12-now-autocomplete-urls-as-you.html) in  the address bar.  Firefox 12 is now in aurora.  Interested people can download it from [here](http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/aurora/).

Answer (score 1):

Type **about:config**, answer that you will be careful, and then search for **keyword.URL**

Typing the following string there will make Firefox's address bar behaviour look a bit more closer to Chrome's:

> http://www.google.com/search?btnG=Google+Search&q=

and set **keyword.enabled** to **true**.

See http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/759303

To make Firefox look even closer to Chrome, you might also consider downloading the theme https://addons.mozilla.org/en-uS/firefox/addon/fxchrome/ as well as putting the downloads on the bottom bar, just like Chrome does: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/download-statusbar/

Tested on 16.0.1 on a Mac.

Answer (score 0):

Find a term where it doesn't work as well as in Chrome and file a bug report.

Comment: May be he is suggesting, auto complete for search terms, which google chrome prefetch from google search suggestion. Whch is not available in firefox due to privacy reason

Comment: Hm. That shouldn't stop him from filing an enhancement request?

Answer (score 0):

I know it isn't exactly the answer you are looking for, but you could always just press [TAB]. Seems almost as fast as autocomplete.

Or you could wait for FF12, when this behavior will come shipped.

Answer (score 0):

As of 2019, the prospector extensions and the other options mentioned are not available any more.

A solution was mentioned on [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/firefox/comments/a6sy1r/firefox_location_bar_autocomplete_suggest_most/eby0tds). If you got to *Library* and then *Bookmarks*, *Show all bookmarks* (alternatively press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd>), each bookmark has a keyword entry. By adding the short version of the website, Firefox will proceed directly to the bookmarked URL instead of the incomplete URL.

[See screenshot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ldyLH.png)

You need a shortcut for each substring of the desired URL:

- e
- ex
- exa
- exam
- ...
- example.com